# Are there any applicable options to Angular ui-select2 directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ui-select2, angularjs-select2

Given the following Angular selec2 controller:

```
                <select ui-select2 id="projectListSelection" data-placeholder="Select a Project ..." ng-model="selectedProject">
                    @*ng-options="project.WebsiteName for project in projectList"*@
                    <option value=''></option>
                    <option ng-repeat="project in projectList" ng-value="'{{ project.WebsiteGUID }}'">{{project.WebsiteName}}</option>
                </select>
```

Model data is retrieved as follows from the controller:

```
    $scope.projectList = dataFactory.getList("")   // no parameters
                            .success(function (result) {
                                $scope.projectList = result.value;
                                $("#projectListSelection").select2({ width: '240' });
                            })
                            .error(function (error) {
                                customUIFunctions.showError("Data Error - Unable to Load Project List"); // use default error message
                                console.log("data error");
                            });
```

Here's the issue:

1. When the control first appears on the screen, it looks like a plain old `select` drop-down control
2. For a fraction of a second, then its width goes to 0
3. The control's UI is updated again to look like the `select2` control, however its width is only as small as the placeholder
4. After the control is loaded with data, it then resizes to 240px

When I try setting the width before the data is retrieved (before `$scope.projectList = ...`) I get the following errors:

> query function not defined for Select2 s2id_projectListSelection ...
>   angular.js:9402 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded ...

Which makes sense as the DOM isn't fully loaded. So...

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#projectListSelection").select2({ width: '240' });
    });
```

However I still see the same issue, where the width conforms first to the placeholder, then to the wider setting once data is loaded.

I managed to get around this doing:

```
<select ui-select2 id="projectListSelection" style="width:240px;" . . .
```

However, that's kind of ugly.

**The questions:**

1. Is there a width option that will hold true whether or not data is loaded?
2. Is there a placeholder option that will allow me to display a message such as "Loading Data..." then display a different message ie. "Select a project ..." once the data is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your best option here is probably custom CSS that overrides the default.
2. Create a variable in your controller scope called `placeholder` with the initial value of "Loading data..." then watch for your data to load and change scope.placholder to "Select a Project...". Then on your element use placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"